# Using VLOOKUP is there a way to show the result as value similar to number instead of ' N/A, True, False, Yes or No?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

So I am trying to find out what portfolios has dropped from Month A and Month B
But my output using VLOOKUP comes as 'N/A' but I would like the result to show
value of what is not available in in column B with data from Column A

I have attached a pic of what I have and how  I would like it look like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC4jQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxs4u.png)

Comment: Include the formula what you are using now.

Comment: Can you include the formula as well as the sample input you are using for the below example where the issue is occurring. I presume possibly a formatting issue breaking your logic.

Comment: What about `=IF(B3="","", VLOOKUP(...))`?

Comment: I used this formula =VLOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$A$157380,1,0)
I gave a Column Gap in Between

Answer (score 0):

=iferror(Vlookup "Your Original criteria"),"Col A")

E.g.

In Row 4

```
=Iferror(vlookup(A4,B:B,1,false),A4)
```